# Connect to two wifi networks with one wifi network card on Windows (one for lan, one for internet)

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lan, wifi-configuration

I have a ZONE WIFI with my android celphone activated and connected via my network wifi card, so I can't connect to my LAN network via wifi at the same time, there is a way that I can connect both at the same time, one for LAN and one for Internet, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am correctly understanding this question, because it is phrased quite oddly, but I am understanding the question to be something like this:

You have two wireless networks, but you would like to connect to both of the wireless networks at one time using a device containing only one wireless network interface.

Accordingly, if you do not have two wireless network cards, it is not possible to do such a thing. However, there are several pieces of software that you may attempt to use, and they may or may not be able to allow access to both; but if you are trying to combine a LAN and WLAN connection, Im not sure how well any of those things will be.

If it is possible, I would **highly** suggest you simply create a "BRIDGED CONNECTION" on your system - which would be connected to Ethernet for your LAN network, and Wifi for your internet access connection.

This is assuming you are able to connect one or the other to an Ethernet connection to do so. If you are unable to connect to Ethernet whatsoever, you have a very slim chance of being able to do this.

**However** if this is not what you mean, you may be referring to the idea that is discussed in the following link:

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/34203-42-wireless-routers-internet-possible

In order to give you a more concise answer, I would first need to know under which idea your question falls.

Comment: External links can break, in which case that last part of your answer wouldn't make much sense.  It's better to include enough information within the answer so that it's self-contained, and use the link for attribution and further reading.  In this case, describe the gist of the idea from the link here (a sentence or two), in addition to the link.  Thanks.